# Fastboot command to reboot in recovery mode?

Tags: command, fastboot

Is there a fastboot command to reboot in factory mode?

I've tried fastboot reboot factory and got no success

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I have always used
"fastboot reboot-recovery"